# css menu with borders move off page?

Tags: html, css

[image]

css menu with borders move off page with margin:0;

I want add a boarder to my css links and not have the top overflow on top of the page.  I've included my custom.css page the index.php
I want to keep  body{margin:0;background-color:#ddd;color:#0000ff;}

```
html{font-family:sans-serif;  font-size: 14px;
}

 body{margin:0;
 background-color:#ddd;
 color:#0000ff;
 }

a{
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-width: 5px 5px 5px 5px;

}

a:hover {
font-family:sans-serif;
 color:#83F52C;
```

Comment: have a look to box-sizing and border-box.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `display` property of the links to `inline-block`. Note that this will cause the links wrapping behavior to change (each link will wrap as a whole rather than part way through). However, given that wrapping a link part-way would look very strange if it has a colored border, I assume this is what you would want.

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #0000ff;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
a:hover {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #83F52C;
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Zulu.ieo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a>Here is a link</a>
  <a>A veeeeeeeeeeery long link</a>
  <a>Another link</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You!   display: inline-block;  helped!

Comment: No problem! If this is the solution you went with though please accept it so the question shows up as answered.